# Windows 10 VPN into Azure VNet (P2S). Server name not resolving when browsing via Windows Explorer

Tags: vpn, azure, windows-10

So I was able to successfully setup a Point To Site connection from my local Windows 10 machine to my Azure Virtual Network.  I'm not sure if this issue I'm having is really Azure related or just some VPN setting I'm missing.

I can ping the server using the IP address/FQDN/and hostname from my local machine once I've connected via VPN.  My machine has also been joined to the domain.  That all works fine and great.  It's when I go and try to browse to the server (or any server) on the VNET in Azure that I run into problems.  I'm trying to access the file share I created for instance and I cannot get to it using the hostname.  However, I am able to reach the file share using the FQDN. I'd really like to use the regular server names when I am browsing around on the network.

I find it odd that pinging works for everything across the board but using Windows Explorer limits me to using the FQDN to reach resources.  I've been googling the last couple of days for a fix and so far I've been able to get to the point I'm at now.

I'm reaching out to see if anyone has any ideas.  Thanks.

VM Servers in Azure are Windows 2012 Datacenter. 
Local machine is Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Just for giggles, can you disable the firewall on the target server and see if you are still blocked?

Comment: How do you configure the DNS settings of the server on Azure? Azure DNS or custom DNS?

Comment: Disabling firewall doesn't solve the issue

Comment: In Azure the DNS is custom DNS using 2 DC's.  I've set all the servers to have static IPs.

Comment: I feel like this has to be tied to the win10 notion of public/private networks and what services are available when you connect.. but i'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the custom DNS, then please check the DNS settings of the client when it has established the VPN connection to Azure.

First, please make sure that the DNS server is your DC.

Second, please make sure that the DNS suffix is correct.

When you try to resolve a single label name, the system will append the DNS suffix to make it become FQDN. Then the DNS client will send the request to the DNS server for resolving.